# How to change the icon of folder in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

After integrating Google Colab with Google Drive (add it as app to drive) and create a test Colab notebook, I can see the Colab folder in the drive, but it's of different colour, yellow.

[image]

Does that mean the icon of a folder in Google Drive can be changed? and if so, how to customise these folder icons in Google Drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the color can be changed. Open the folder, click the triangle next to the name and then the 'Change color' option:

[image]